# How to Chain multiple custom filters with AngualrJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

How can i chain multiple filters using AngularJS. My case is i have 3 dropdown menu i want to use as filters to filter out data in a table. I just created a plunk to demonstrate what i want to acchieve, here is the URL of my [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/EdGutDSXilkjyMqB2pxH)

Filtering is working, but not giving the correct result based on what i select i dropdowns to filter on.

HTML

```
<select ng-model="filterItem.Org">
   <option value="">Filter on Org</option>
  <option value="org1">org1</option>
  <option value="org2">org2</option>
  <option value="org3">org3</option>
</select>
 <select ng-model="filterItem.Period">
   <option value="">Filter on Period</option>
  <option value="2017">2017</option>
  <option value="2018">2018</option>
</select>
<select ng-model="filterItem.ActionPlan">
  <option value="">Filter on ActionPlan</option>
  <option value="Plan1">Plan1</option>
  <option value="Plan2">Plan2</option>
  <option value="Plan3">Plan3</option>
  <option value="Plan4">Plan4</option>
</select><br><br>

<table id="actionPlans" >
<thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Period</th>
      <th>AssociatedPlan</th>
      <th>Organization</th>
   </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="actionPlan in actionPlans | filter:customFilter">
     <td></td>
     <td>{{actionPlan.Title}}</td>
     <td>{{actionPlan.Period}}</td>
     <td>{{actionPlan.ActionPlan}}</td>
     <td>{{actionPlan.Org}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Javascript Controller:

```
var app = angular.module('drpFiltering', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.name = 'Dropdown filtering';
$scope.actionPlans = [
    {
        Org: 'org1',
        Title: 'Gjennomføre julebord',
        Period: '2017',
        ActionPlan: 'Kommunedelplan Helse',

    },
    {
        Org: 'org1',
        Title: 'Gjennomføre medarbeiderundersøkelse',
        Period: '2017',
        ActionPlan: 'Handlingsprogram 2017-2020',

    }
   ,
    {
        Org: 'org2',
        Title: 'God økonomistyring',
        Period: '2018',
        ActionPlan: 'Detaljprogram Helse',

    },
     {
        Org: 'org2',
        Title: 'Kjøre medarbeiderundersøkelse',
        Period: '2018',
        ActionPlan: 'Kommunedelplan Helse',

    }
     ,{
        Org: 'org2',
        Title: 'Gjennomføre medarbeiderundersøkelse ',
        Period: '2017',
        ActionPlan: 'Temaplan Helse',

    }
    , {
        Org: 'org3',
        Title: 'Korrupsjonsforebyggende opplæring',
        Period: '2017',
        ActionPlan: 'plan2',

    },
    {
       Org: 'org3',
        Title: 'opplæring',
        Period: '2018',
        ActionPlan: 'plan3',

    },
    {
        Org: 'org1',
        Title: 'opplæring',
        Period: '2018',
        ActionPlan: 'plan4',

    }
];
$scope.customFilter = function (data) {
    if ($scope.filterItem !== undefined) {
        if ($scope.filterItem.Org === data.Org) {
          return true;
        } 
        if ($scope.filterItem.Period === data.Period) {
          return true;
        }
        if ($scope.filterItem.ActionPlan === data.ActionPlan) {
           return true;
        } 
        else{
          return false;
        }  
    }
 };
});
```

Any help with this will be realy apprissiated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution (HTML only), without declaring a custom function in your Angular controller:

```
<tr ng-repeat="actionPlan in actionPlans | filter: {ActionPlan: filterItem.ActionPlan, Period: filterItem.Period, Org: filterItem.Org}">
```

[**Forked your Plunker here.**](http://plnkr.co/edit/mOgt4JIKAodf0gezq6VP?p=preview)

Answer (score -1):

> HTML

```
<select ng-model="filterItem.Org">
   <option value="">Filter on Org</option>
  <option value="org1">org1</option>
  <option value="org2">org2</option>
  <option value="org3">org3</option>
</select>
 <select ng-model="filterItem.Period">
   <option value="">Filter on Period</option>
  <option value="2017">2017</option>
  <option value="2018">2018</option>
</select>
<select ng-model="filterItem.ActionPlan">
  <option value="">Filter on ActionPlan</option>
  <option value="Plan1">Plan1</option>
  <option value="Plan2">Plan2</option>
  <option value="Plan3">Plan3</option>
  <option value="Plan4">Plan4</option>
</select><br><br>

<table id="actionPlans" >
<thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Period</th>
      <th>AssociatedPlan</th>
      <th>Organization</th>
   </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="actionPlan in actionPlans | filter:{Org:filterItem.Org,Period:filterItem.Period,ActionPlan:filterItem.ActionPlan}">
     <td></td>
     <td>{{actionPlan.Title}}</td>
     <td>{{actionPlan.Period}}</td>
     <td>{{actionPlan.ActionPlan}}</td>
     <td>{{actionPlan.Org}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

> Angularjs

```
var app = angular.module('drpFiltering', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.name = 'Dropdown filtering';
$scope.actionPlans = [
    {
        Org: 'org1',
        Title: 'Gjennomføre julebord',
        Period: '2017',
        ActionPlan: 'Kommunedelplan Helse',

    },
    {
        Org: 'org1',
        Title: 'Gjennomføre medarbeiderundersøkelse',
        Period: '2017',
        ActionPlan: 'Handlingsprogram 2017-2020',

    }
   ,
    {
        Org: 'org2',
        Title: 'God økonomistyring',
        Period: '2018',
        ActionPlan: 'Detaljprogram Helse',

    },
     {
        Org: 'org2',
        Title: 'Kjøre medarbeiderundersøkelse',
        Period: '2018',
        ActionPlan: 'Kommunedelplan Helse',

    }
     ,{
        Org: 'org2',
        Title: 'Gjennomføre medarbeiderundersøkelse ',
        Period: '2017',
        ActionPlan: 'Temaplan Helse',

    }
    , {
        Org: 'org3',
        Title: 'Korrupsjonsforebyggende opplæring',
        Period: '2017',
        ActionPlan: 'plan2',

    },
    {
       Org: 'org3',
        Title: 'opplæring',
        Period: '2018',
        ActionPlan: 'plan3',

    },
    {
        Org: 'org1',
        Title: 'opplæring',
        Period: '2018',
        ActionPlan: 'plan4',

    }
]});
```